# Determined those positive integers $n$ such that there exists a regular tournament of orders $n$

Tags: graph-theory

Determined those positive integers $n$ such that there exists a regular tournament of orders $n$

I know that a tournament is a oriented complete graph, and every complete graph $K_n $ has $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
n  \\
2  \\
 \end{array} \right) $ edges.

If the graph is $r$-regular then every vertex has degree $r$, by the first theorem of graph theory, the sum degree of all vertices is twice the size, so

$$nr= 2 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
n  \\
2  \\
 \end{array} \right) $$
$$nr=(n-1)n$$

$$n=r+1$$

but the book say $n=2r+1$. Did I do something wrong or there is a typo in the book?

Comment: You have a correct relationship between the degree of a (regular) complete *unoriented* graph and its number of vertices.  Presumably in your book $r$ stands for outdegree (or indegree), which is half of the unoriented degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you need to be a bit careful. I believe you are referring to the result often known as the handshaking lemma, which says that in an undirected graph, $\sum_{v\in V(G)}\deg(v)=2|E(G)|$. The reason the $2$ is on the right is that, in the sum on the left, each edge is being counted *twice* (once for each of its endpoints). You can apply a similar idea to a directed graph, say by counting the total of the out-degrees (number of edges leaving a vertex) over all vertices, but now you're not counting each edge twice anymore. So the analogous result for directed graphs is that $\sum_{v\in V(G)}\textrm{outdeg}(v) = |E(G)|$. Applying this to your situation, you get the equality $rn={n\choose 2}$, which leads to $n=2r+1$.

You can also see this just by thinking at what must happen at each vertex. Every vertex has degree $n-1$ and for the tournament to be regular, half those edges must be entering the vertex, and half leaving. Hence you better have $2r=n-1$.

But note that this is only a *necessary* condition for an $r$-regular tournament to exist. You also need to show that if $n=2r+1$, then there actually exists an $r$-regular tournament.

Answer (score 2):

The *regular* in *regular tournament* is a little different from the *regular* in *regular (undirected) graph*: a tournament is regular if the in-degree of every vertex is the same as the out-degree. The $r$ in your book is apparently the in-degree (or out-degree) of each vertex, so it’s half the total degree. Each edge contributes just $1$ to the sum of the in-degrees, so the correct equation is

$$nr=\binom{n}2\;,$$

and hence $n=2r+1$.

It’s also true that there is a regular tournament of every odd order: see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938947/prove-that-there-exist-regular-tournament-of-every-odd-order-but-there-is-no-reg) and answer.